# VBA RegEx extracting data from within a string

Tags: regex, vba

I am new to RegEx and I can't seem to figure out why this is not working.  I had it working but lost my data.  I have tried all sorts of variations and I can't remember what I did to get this to work before.

I have fields with the following variations

> "**SB123**"
>   "**some data SB 1234**"
>   "**some data SB 1234567 and more data**"
>   "**SB1234.**" etc...

and what I would like to extract is the SB and number portion.  Can someone please help?

```
Sub ExtractSBData()

Dim regEx
Dim i As Long
Dim pattern As String
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
regEx.pattern = ".*(SB\s*\d{3}\d+).*"

    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If (regEx.test(Cells(i, 14).value)) Then
            Cells(i, 16).value = regEx.Replace(Cells(i, 14).value, "$1")
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Sorry, I realized I didn't explain what it's currently doing.  Currently it is only working if the grouping is surrounded by data (ie "**data here SB123 and here** but not "**SB123 data here**" or "**data here SB123**").  In addition, it is putting the whole line in cells(i, 16) instead of just the SB number portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just want to try `SB\s*\d{3,}`.

If that doesn't work (because of data preceding or following the text you're looking for), remember that the `.` operator in RegEx matches every character *except* `\n` (newline). Then you could try `[.\n]*SB\s*\d{3,}[.\n]*`.

Let me know if one of those work for you.

Comment: Well, the second one didn't work but the first one did if I altered it like this .*(SB\s*\d{3,}).* but I don't see how that is really any different from what I had so why is it working???  I used the first one straight up but all it did was replace the text I wanted with $1 so I added the () but then it was setting the value to the whole line so I added the .* on the outsides.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. The reason why the first is not working (I think) is the following: `\d{3}\d+`. I think the matching for that part may have been ambiguous?? At least with `\d{3,}`, what you're saying is that you must match a minimum of 3 digits. Actually, I just tested `\d{3}\d+` in my Regex tester and indeed, it doesn't match. For Visual Studio 2010/2012, you should install the [Regular Expression Tester](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bf883ae3-188b-43bc-bd29-6235c4195d1f) extension--it's a great tool!