# Extract four numbers without brackets from a bracketed entry, if entry exists

Tags: regex, vba

What I have:

- A list of about 1000 titles of reports in column B.
- Some of these titles have a four digit number surrounded by brackets (eg: `(3672)`) somewhere in a string of text and numbers.
- I want to extract these four numbers  - **without brackets** - in column C in the same row.
- If there is no four digit number with brackets in column B, then to return "" in column C.

*What I have so far:*

I can successfully identify the cells in column B which have four digits surrounded by brackets. The problem is it returns the whole title including the four numbers.

Taken from: [VBA RegEx extracting data from within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675675/vba-regex-extracting-data-from-within-a-string)

NB: I am Using Excel Professional Plus 2010, have checked the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5".

```
Sub ExtractTicker()

Dim regEx
Dim i As Long
Dim pattern As String
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
regEx.pattern = "(\()([0-9]{4})(\))"

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If (regEx.Test(Cells(i, 2).Value)) Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = regEx.Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, "$2")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`regEx.pattern = "(.*\()([0-9]{4})(\).*)"`

the `.*` and the start and end of the string ensure you capture the entire string, then this is fully substituted by the 2nd submatch *([0-9]{4})*

To fully optimise the code

- use variant arrays rather than ranges
- setting *Global* and *IgnoreCase* is redundant when you are running a case insensitive match on the full string
- you are using late binding so you dont need the Reference

*code*

```
Sub ExtractTicker()

Dim regEx As Object
Dim pattern As String
Dim X
Dim lngCNt As Long

X = Range([b1], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regEx
    .pattern = "(.*\()([0-9]{4})(\).*)"
    For lngCNt = 1 To UBound(X)
        If .Test(X(lngCNt, 1)) Then
            X(lngCNt, 1) = .Replace(X(lngCNt, 1), "$2")
        Else
            X(lngCNt, 1) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next
End With

[c1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), 1).Value2 = X

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi brettdj, code works like a charm. And many thanks for the clear explanations made to the code. Very much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to capture the surrounding text.  `.*\((\d{4})\).*` would suffice (and replace using `$1`)

Comment: That is correct in this case - although the simplification is minor. I used a default pattern that I apply for such cases to gives me access to all 3 parts of the string (prefix, match, suffix) in case I want to modify the replacement. Thx for the comment.